# How can amp-script detect if web app is running standalone?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, amp-html

I am trying use amp-script to count pageviews in standalone mode. The plain javascript method using

```
window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches
```

doesn't work, it generates the *window.matchMedia is not a function* error messsage. Any ideea?

Comment: See Javascript example here. Not sure about amp-script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735869/check-if-user-has-already-installed-pwa-to-homescreen-on-chrome/51735941#51735941

Comment: @Mathias, amp-script has a lot of limitations, one of them is that matchMedia doesn't work. Thank you anyway.